# XSLT Get attribute by string

Tags: xml, xslt, attributes, exslt

I'm wondering if I can get a attr value by a string query on a XML element. Example:

```
<xsl:variable name="astr">
color
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="$treeItem/@$astr"></xsl:value-of>
```

Which means:

```
$treeItem/@$astr   results in ---> $treeItem/@color
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have set up your variable it is not even a string but a result tree fragment or a temporary tree.

To have a string you need e.g. `<xsl:variable name="astr" select="'color'"/>`.

As for selecting an attribute by the name you have in your variable, use `$treeItem/@*[local-name() = $astr]`.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I need!